# Filling NaN and Empty Value wit other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

I want to filling NaN and Empty Value wit other column value, in this case column `barcode_y` filled by column `barcode_x`

Here's my data

```
    id      barcode_x     barcode_y A   B
0   7068    38927887      38927895  0   12
1   7068    38927895      38927895  0   1
2   7068    39111141      38927895  0   4
3   7116    73094237                18  309
4   7154    37645215      37645215  0   9
5   7342    86972909           NaN  7   25
```

Here's what I need

```
    id      barcode_x     barcode_y A   B
0   7068    38927887      38927895  0   12
1   7068    38927895      38927895  0   1
2   7068    39111141      38927895  0   4
3   7116    73094237      73094237  18  309
4   7154    37645215      37645215  0   9
5   7342    86972909      86972909  7   25
```

How suppose I do this?

Comment: I think this will work when barcode_y is `Nan` `df.barcode_y.combine_first(df.barcode_x)`

Comment: @Orenshi : It Works

Comment: @Orenshi, you can post that as an answer.

Comment: @Orenshi, even it half of the answer, you still give answer

Comment: Okay I posted as answer. I also have suggestion on how to handle the object dtype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
x, y = df['barcode_x'], df['barcode_y']
y.mask(y.eq('') | y.isna(), x)

0    38927895
1    38927895
2    38927895
3    73094237
4    37645215
5    86972909
Name: barcode_y, dtype: object
```

Comment: Damn this is a nice one. Except in my case I'm on `pandas 0.20.2` so I have to use `y.isnull()`

Comment: More generic answer, awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can convert empty values with `NaN` and then use `.fillna()`.

```
df['barcode_y'].replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True).replace('',np.nan).fillna(df['barcode_x']).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0    38927895
1    38927895
2    38927895
3    73094237
4    37645215
5    86972909
Name: barcode_y, dtype: int32
```

Comment: @NabihBawazir glad, I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend masking to accomplish what you want:

```
df['barcode_y'][df['barcode_y'].isna()] = df['barcode_x'][df['barcode_y'].isna()]
```

This will work universally, not depending if the columns are sorted in some way, for example if `barcode_y` is before or after `barcode_x`.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isna'` in my case

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using? I can use `isna()` on `Series` and `DataFrames`.

Comment: Do you know how to check, this is installed by my 'DevOps' but it is Anaconda 5.0

Comment: `pd.__version__`

Comment: I am using pandas 0.20.3

Comment: Or did you perhaps forget the `()` after `isna`? It has to be `df['barcode_y'].isna()` where `df` is the name of your `DataFrame`. Or did you delete some of the `[]`? My method definetely works for `Series` and `DataFrames` and is the most universal method, since this also works for numpy arrays (if you remove the column access).

Comment: Ok, with version 0.20.3 you need to update `pandas`. If you have Anaconda, open the navigator, go to environments, look for `pandas` and mark for upgrade. Or open the anaconda prompt and type `conda update pandas`.

Comment: @NabihBawazir FYI... I'm almost on same `pandas` version as you (0.20.2). `isna` is not available in our version but I think you can use `isnull` if you go with @Scott1 's solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd use combine_first in this case... especially if `barcode_y` is not `dtype object`

```
df.barcode_y.combine_first(df.barcode_x)
```

If `barcode_y` is `dtype object`, I think you can go this extra step like below:

```
>>> df
   barcode_x barcode_y
0          1         0
1        123      None
2        543
>>> df.barcode_y = df.barcode_y.combine_first(df.barcode_x)
>>> df
   barcode_x barcode_y
0          1         0
1        123       123
2        543
>>> df.loc[df.barcode_y.str.strip()=='', 'barcode_y'] = df.loc[df.barcode_y.str.strip()=='', 'barcode_x']
>>> df
   barcode_x  barcode_y
0          1          0
1        123        123
2        543        543
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this,

```
def fillValues(x):    
   x = x['barcode_x'] if np.isnan(x['barcode_y']) else x['barcode_y']
   return x

df["barcode_y"] = df.apply(lambda x : fillValues(x),axis=1)
print(df)
```